# Corona Lua SQLite

Tags: sql, select, lua, coronasdk

this is my first question on stackOverflow.
I'm working with Corona and I'm having an issue accessing a SQLdb (I'm a bit of a SQL noob.)

I'm trying to access and return a value I've stored in the database.
Here's some code samples:

```
print("---------------- How I Create New Player Save Data")
local entry = [[CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playerData (key STRING PRIMARY KEY, content INTEGER);]]
db:exec(entry)

entry = [[INSERT INTO playerData VALUES ("LastLoginTime", 0);]]
db:exec( entry )
entry = [[INSERT INTO playerData VALUES ("Credits", 1000);]]
db:exec( entry )
entry = [[INSERT INTO playerData VALUES ("Level", 1);]]
db:exec( entry )
```

Now this function works, it will print everything in the db (i pass in 'dbName'):

```
--print all the table contents
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM "..dbName) do
  local text = row.key..":  "..row.content
end
```

This doesn't work, it returns '0':

```
local grabCredits = "SELECT content FROM playerData WHERE key='Credits'"
  local credits = db:exec(grabCredits)
  print("-- value: "..credits)
```

Neither does this, also returns '0':

```
local grabCredits = "SELECT key FROM playerData WHERE content>=10"
  local credits = db:exec(grabCredits)
  print("-- value: "..credits)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Maybe I need to use another function call on the db other than exec(). I realize I could iterate through the db every time I want to access a single entry, but that just seems inefficient.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want results, you must use some form of iterator. SQLite always returns *rows* for a query result.

Comment: So, just to be clear. I must ALWAYS iterate through an entire db when I want to access an entry in a table? There is no other way to grab an entry?

Comment: Yes, kinda. You can do separate prepare step and finalize/reset calls on the statement, but the loop really doesn't have much overhead since it will only run one iteration if there is only one result. Also, if you only want one result when there are many, you can break from the loop.

Comment: Cool. I don't understand enough of SQL to "separate (and) prepare step and finalize/reset calls on the statement." But everything else makes sense. Thanks a lot for the info!

Comment: BTW, you are not iterating through the "entire db," only through the result set of the query.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to what I'm using to retrieve one result from my database and works well for me.

```
local query = "SELECT content FROM playerData WHERE key = 'Credits' LIMIT 1"

local queryResultTable = {}

local queryFunction = function(userData, numberOfColumns, columnValues, columnTitles)

    for i = 1, numberOfColumns do

        queryResultTable[columnTitles[i]] = columnValues[i]

    end

end

db:exec(query, queryFunction)

for k,v in pairs(queryResultTable) do

    print(k,v)

end
```